# Use selected UIPicker row as text for custom UITableViewCell UILabel SWIFT

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uipickerview

I have been banging against this for days now, trying a number of different approaches. I have a UITableView with custom cells containing two UILabels. On selecting the cell, a UIPicker is revealed, and a variable is set referencing which cell was tapped.

Once a selection is made in the UIPicker, I need to take that value and use it to replace the existing .text of one of the cell labels. I have tried using .viewWithTag a few different ways (first tagging the label itself, then the entire cell) and nothing works.

My didSelect for the picker is:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        println("pickerView did select row \(row)")

        if(self.getStatus() == "newFirst"){
            switch (editingField){
            case 0:
                var l:NewOrderCell! = tableView.viewWithTag(editingField) as? NewOrderCell
                //the label in the custom cell is called 'Text'
                l.Text.text = pickerData[row]
                println("should be changing \(l.Text.text) into \(pickerData[row])")
            default:
                var l:NewOrderCell! = tableView.viewWithTag(editingField) as? NewOrderCell
                l.Text.text = pickerData[row]
            }
        }
        picker.hidden=true
    }
```

and my cellForRowAtIndexPath for the table is:

```
var cell:NewOrderCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NewOrderCell") as NewOrderCell
                //label
                cell.Label.text = self.newOrder[indexPath.row]
                //text
                cell.Text.text = "Please Select"
                cell.tag = indexPath.row
                return cell
```

I know my goal, but can't get a handle on the proper way to reference a cell within a table from another method. Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you try using delegates? You can subClass the UIPicker, define protocols in that class and implement those protocol functions in your tableview. Set the delegate of the subClassed UIPIcker as the tableview and in the table view class implement a function which takes text, and cell index as input and updates the same. Comment back in case you want the code..

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with a solution that works, but I feel is inelegant and hard to maintain: when the picker row is selected, that text is written to the array that was used to originally populate the table (overwriting the original item), and then I reload the table, so that the new value appears. So, it's something like this:

```
var truth: [String:String] = ["Key1":"","Key2":"","Key3":""]
var keys:[String] = ["Key1", "Key2","Key3"]

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
var cell:NewOrderCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NewOrderCell") as NewOrderCell
     //label
     cell.Label.text = keys[indexPath.row]
     //textfield
     if(truth[keys[indexPath.row]] == ""){
            cell.Text.text = "Please Select"
     }
     else{
            cell.Text.text = truth[keys[indexPath.row]]
     }
     return cell
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    truth[keys[editingField]] = pickerData[row]
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
         self.tableView.reloadData()
    })

}
```

Happy to hear better solutions

Comment: Instead of reloading the entire table view, you can try this : 

`[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathOfYourCell] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];`

Comment: Very nice, thanks. Your comment on delegates and subclassing sounds best, but is a bit beyond my comfort level and timelines.